# How do I turn string into datetime values and merge

Tags: python, datetime, merge

[I have a string of yearly data month 1-12, trying to convert it to datetime.month values and then converge it on the main df that already has dt.month values according to some date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bp8nn.png)

```
usage_12month["MONTH"]= pd.to_datetime(usage_12month["MONTH"])
usage_12month['MONTH'] = usage_12month['MONTH'].dt.month
display(usage_12month)
merge = pd.merge(df,usage_12month, how='left',on='MONTH')
```

ValueError: Given date string not likely a datetime.

​get the error on the 1st line

Comment: What is `datetime.month`?

Comment: month, meant to say dt.month

Answer (score 0):

`.dt.month` on a datetime returns an int. So I'm assuming you want to convert `usage_12month["MONTH"]` from a string to an int to be able to merge it with the other df.

There is a simplier way than converting it to a datetime. You could replace the first two lines by `usage_12month["MONTH"]= pd.to_numeric(usage_12month["MONTH"])` and it should work.

--

The error you get on the first line is because you don't specify to the to_datetime function how to interpet the string as a datetime (the number in the string could represent a day, an hour...).

To make your way work you have to give a 'format' parameter to the to_datetime function. In your case, your string contains only the month number, so the format string would be '%m' (see https://strftime.org/) : `usage_12month["MONTH"]= pd.to_datetime(usage_12month["MONTH"], format = '%m')`

When you're supplying the function with a "usual" date fromat like 'yyyy/mm/dd' it guesses how to interpret it, but it is alway better to provide a format to the function.